# How do I add Chrome app launcher to taskbar after restoring Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I did a system restore and all taskbar shortcuts were erased.

How can I add the Chrome app launcher back? I also wonder, isn't restore supposed to preserve all files except programs?

Comment: best and official answer at :
https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/answer/3060053?hl=en
under heading "Find the app launcher"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can drag `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Chrome App Launcher.lnk` to the Windows taskbar to restore the App launcher shortcut, or better yet you can copy the icon to `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Google Chrome` instead if you have the Administrator privileges.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Also, as a shortcut, if you're too lazy to type your own name, you can also use:
`C:/Users/%username%/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Chrome App Launcher.lnk` and it will auto-magically fill in your username in place of %username%

Comment: Or you can use magic of greater circle called `%userprofile%` on that way: `%userprofile%/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Chrome App Launcher.lnk`

Comment: Although I could not see that ninja icon :(

Answer (score 17):

(The problem with mob's answer is I also didn't find the prebuilt shortcut)

The answer is: create a shortcut with `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --show-app-list` as the target, then change the icon to the app launcher icon and pin it.

Detailed walkthrough:

- open `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\`
- right click `chrome.exe`, send to desktop (create shortcut)
- open the shortcut properties
- append the `--show-app-list` flag in "target"
- click Change Icon, the icon is already there
- click OK
- open it and pin it

Comment: This is the correct answer

Comment: Just used this solution and want to point out that (for me in Win10 anyway) pinning the window the shortcut opens merely creates a taskbar icon which opens a standard Chrome tab when clicked. However, if I right-drag the shortcut I created per your instructions to the taskbar, THAT does allow me to have the traditional App Launcher taskbar button again.

Answer (score 5):

Try this: go to
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/launcher

There you can find the blue 'install app button'.

But sometimes it may not be there.
In that case, you may want to try to make your own shortcut, point to:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --show-app-list

Comment: There's no blue button anymore.